# jQuery .animate with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm total beginner with Javascript and jQuery. I'm trying to animate a div IF a var is true but it's not working. Could someone point me in the right direction!

Here's my code so far:

```
var prompti = prompt("Please enter true value");

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (prompti === true) {
        $('#test').animate({"left": "300px"}, 200)
    };
 });
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would help

Comment: You should explain which value you expect the user to enter. Then we can suggest a solution. Just posting your code doesn't tell us what you are trying to achieve. What does "true value" mean?

Comment: Here's an old animate that might help you - based on a click and changes in opacity, size. You can play with a variety of jQuery commands http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/xaNqW/

Answer (score 1):

`Prompt` returns value as string so you should check

```
if (prompti === 'true') //match as string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working exemple:

http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge2014/369e7av4/1/

```
        var prompti = prompt("Please enter true value");


        alert(typeof prompti);
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if (prompti === "true") {
                alert('animate');
                $('#test').animate({"left": "300px"}, 200)
            };
        });
```

The prompt function returns a string and you are validating against a boolean.

Comment: We all started somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary semicolon after your second last `}` and you're missing one on the preceding line.

I've also edited your code a little, here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/6q5vganh/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}
#test {
    background-color:grey;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var prompti = prompt("Please enter true value");

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (prompti !== null) {
        $('#test').animate({
            "left": "300px"
        }, 200);
    }
});
```